# $(G,\cdot)$ is abelian $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\forall a,b \in G: (ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

Show that for a group $(G,\cdot)$ the following statements are equivalent:

$A:$ $(G,\cdot)$ is abelian

$B:\forall a,b \in G: (ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$

---

$A \Longrightarrow B:$

Since $(G,\cdot)$ is a group:

$\forall a,b \in G: (ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$

and since $(G,\cdot)$ is commutative:

$b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}$

$B \Longrightarrow A:$

Since $B$ holds:

$e=(ab)(ab)^{-1}=(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1}=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$

Suppose $(G,\cdot)$ is not abelian, then:

$aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ has to equal $e$ which would mean, that since $(G,\cdot)$ is associative,

$a(ba^{-1}b^{-1})=e$

This implies $(ba^{-1}b^{-1})=a^{-1}$

And since $(aba^{-1})b^{-1}=e \Longrightarrow (aba^{-1})=b$

Which means $ba^{-1}=a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $ab=b=ba^{-1}$

in this case we can calculate $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})=ba^{-1}$ which supposed to be $e$.

But since in a group the inverse has to be specific and unique, this is a contradicition!

Since weve choosen $aa^{-1}=e\,\,\,\wedge bb^{-1}=e$

$\Longrightarrow (G,\cdot)$ has to abelian

$B\Longrightarrow A$

So concluding to $A \Longleftrightarrow B$

$\Box$

---

Could someone look over it? Last exercise on group theory I messed up as some of you have seen already :) Is this correct this time?

Comment: Why is $ba^{-1}=a^{-1}$?

Comment: You don't have to make the proof lengthy. From here: $ e=(ab)(ab)^{-1}=(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1}=aba^{-1}b^{-1} $, You may argue that since $e=aba^{-1}b^{-1} $, hence  $(eb) b^{-1}= aba^{-1}b^{-1} \implies b=aba^{-1}\implies (ba) a^{-1}= aba^{-1}\implies ba=ab $  and hence proved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $A\implies B$ is fine. I would write the last line as
$$
(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}
$$
because that better follows the flow of your argument. But that's a minor aesthetic concern.

For $B\implies A$, I think you need to put more emphasis on the $\forall$. Also, you go from $(ba^{-1}b^{-1})=a^{-1}$ to $ba^{-1}=a^{-1}$, which is just not true.

I would personally choose to go contrapositive, as a first attempt. That is, show $\lnot A\implies \lnot B$. So assume the group isn't abelian, and find some $a,b$ which do not fulfill $B$. So that's what I'll do.

$\lnot A\implies \lnot B$: Since the group is non-abelian, by definition there is some pair of elements $a,b$ such that $ab\neq ba$. Multiply both sides from the right by $a^{-1}b^{-1}$, and you get $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\neq e$, and we're done.

But if you want to prove it directly, that's very doable too: we have, for each $a,b\in G$, that
$$
aba^{-1}b^{-1}=e\\
aba^{-1}=b\\
ab=ba
$$
proving that the group is abelian.

This might shed some light on why $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is called the *commutator* of $a$ and $b$: it measures whether $a$ and $b$ commutes.

Answer (score 2):

An easier proof of the second part will be will be :
$ab$
= $(a^{-1})^{-1}.(b^{-1})^{-1}$
= $(a^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}$  (why ?)
= $((ba)^{-1})^{-1}$ (why? )
= $ba$

So the group is abelian.
Just joined the community, yet to learn latex properly.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide to how we format math on this site. (Also, technically not $\LaTeX$, but rather MathJax, a Javascript imitation.) Welcome to math.stackexchange!

Comment: Thank you Arthur. Really appreciate.